# Upload html to SONY NEX 5R camera

Tags: html, json, camera, sony

Is it possible to upload a html Page to a sony nex 5R camera? I want to call it over the wifi Interface.

I want to take a Photo with the JSON interface. In fact it works with an local page to take a Photo in combination with the smart remote control app. But because of browser limitation of cross side scripting, I cant read the json answer.

If the Html Page is located on the camera, I could read the answer and view the result image.

Is there a way to upload a html page onto the camera?

Then you can control the camera without any app. You just need a wifi device with any browser.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html>
 <title>Sony Remote Control</title>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 SonyConnect = function() {
     $.ajax({
         url: "http://192.168.122.1:8080/sony/camera",
         type: "POST",
         data: "{\"method\":\"startRecMode\",\"params\":[],\"id\":5}",
         dataType: "json"
     });
 };

 SonyRelease = function() {
     var jqxhr = $.ajax({
         url: "http://192.168.122.1:8080/sony/camera",
         type: "POST",
         data: "{\"method\":\"actTakePicture\",\"params\":[],\"id\":18}",
         dataType: "json",
         timeout: 10000
     });
 };

 </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <h1>Sony Remote</h1>

 <button type="button" onclick="SonyConnect()">Connect</button>
 <button type="button" onclick="SonyRelease()">TakePhoto</button>

 </html> 
 </body>
```

Comment: Hey, did you already manage this? I actually find nearly no information about writing custom apps for the camera, so it would be cool if you could post your research anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: I did not solve this problem. Writing external camera Apps is not the problem. [developer.sony.com](https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/) I want to save something on the Camera.